# How to compute $\varphi*\gamma,\psi∗\beta$ and $\psi*\gamma$?

Tags: calculus, geometry, tensors, differential, pullback

let $\alpha,\beta\in\Lambda_1(\Bbb R^3)$ and $\gamma\in\Lambda_2(\Bbb R^3)$ be given by
\begin{align*}
\alpha &= xdx + ydy + zdz,\\
\beta &= xdy − ydx + dz,\\
\gamma &= z^2dx\wedge dy + x^2dy\wedge  dz + y^2dx\wedge  dz.
\end{align*}

Let $\varphi:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ be given by  $\varphi(u, v, w)=(e^w\sin u, e^w \cos u, v^3 − u^3)$  and let $\psi:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^3$ be given by  $\psi(s, t)=(s \cos t, s \sin t, t)$.

How to compute $\varphi*\gamma,\psi∗\beta$ and $\psi*\gamma$ ?

Comment: [ Cries in $\LaTeX$. ]

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: congratulations, you had to take a lot of time to write your problem as best you can, im sorry for those people who give downvote just because this si not in $\LaTeX$. Please, try to update your question and make a question